# Http connection in Angular 5

Tags: json, angular, rest, spring-boot

I am currently building my first Angular 5 application that has to interact with my [Java Rest Web Services](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_introduction.htm) that I built using [Spring Boot]
(https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-boot-tutorial).

I wrote my first HTTP connection by following various tutorials. My goal is to perform a **POST**; I did the following:

I created a file called proxy-config.json *[web services are obtainable in localhost:8080]*:

```
{
    "/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "info"
    }
 }
```

And edited the ***start*** line in package.json to:

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy-config.json",
```

I then wrote a http-post in a save-data.component.ts file *[logMe() is a button click event]*:

```
logMe() {

    let body = JSON.stringify({ "userEmail": this.userEmail, "userPassword": this.userPassword} );
    this.http.post('/logging', body, httpOptions).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log( data );
      },
      error => {
        console.error("There Is Something Wrong\nPlease Try Again Later...");
      }
    );

    console.log ( body );

}
```

The problem is that, when I send the post I receive the following 
error on the browser's console:

```
POST http://localhost:4200/logging 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: This means the server listening on `localhost:4200` doesn't know about `/logging`. What is the expected behavior?

Comment: How do I go about making this work? I've been searching and I cannot seem to find a valid example that works for me.

Comment: I think you mean `target + '/' + logging` or something similar, which you need to have extracted from `proxy-config.json`

Comment: @666DESH666 use some REST client in order to test your Java endpoint. It seems that the problem is there

Comment: And please, read the documentation. You should NOT stringifyi your body. https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request

Comment: My rest works, and I also replaced body with { "userEmail": this.userEmail, "userPassword": this.userPassword }

Comment: Where have you placed the proxy-config.json file? It should be in the root directory.

Comment: How do you start the server listening on port 4200?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try with this one?

```
{
  "/api": {
  "target": "http://localhost:8080",
  "secure": false,
  "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
  }
}
```

Also, make sure proxy-config.json is in root folder

Comment: I now receive this error in the command --> Error: [HPM] Invalid context. Expecting something like: "/api" or ["/api", "/ajax"]

Comment: Ok, then can you add api before all your service calls? This will fix it, I will change my answer if you can add a /api

Comment: Added my api in the backend

Comment: Thanks it works, but I has a problem when it gets to the back-end::Thanks though!

Comment: Welcome. Can you please select the answer?